# Доступ к экземпляру класса из AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Добрый день, сообщество. Подсобите нубу.
Есть класс `Registry`, экземпляр которого, точнее его поля, содержат некие данные.
Далее я посредством `ajax` обращаюсь к файлу `handler.php`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "handler.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "myData=SOME_DATA",
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

А в этом файле `handler.php` мне нужно обработать переданное значение `myData` с использованием значения некоторого поля экземпляра класса `Registry`, которое было установлено ранее. Как мне это сделать? В какую сторону копать? Может в `data` можно вместе со значением `myData` можно передать и экземпляр `Registry`, типа  посредством `json`?

Comment: В php поле принято называть свойством класса.

Comment: Прошу пардону, привычка.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, если в вы можете передать значение поля экземпляра Registry, то так и сделайте

```
$.ajax({
   url: "handler.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
            myData: "SOME_DATA", 
            objectRegistry: Value
   }
   success: function(){
       alert("OK");
   }
});
```

Comment: Расширю вопрос. Одно из полей экземпляра registry содержит ссылку на экземпляр другого класса (в моём случае класса MyModel). Его (экземпляр класса) мне и нужно как-то передать в файл handler.php.

Comment: @АртёмСвистула Попробуй передать это поле в ajax. 
     **<?php $objOne->myModelClass = new MyModel(); ?>**

     **data: {
            myData: "SOME_DATA", 
            objectRegistry: '<?php $objOne->myModelClass; ?>'
     }**
Если передастся объект MyModel в handler.php, то тогда то, что нам и нужно. Если нет, тогда бросьте ошибку, посмотрим, в чем проблема.

Comment: Если бы можно было! Вот прочитал про сериализацию. Буду возле рабочего компа, покопаю в эту степь.

Comment: @АртёмСвистула Точно можно сериализовать объект и передать через ajax.
**data: { myData: "SOME_DATA", objectRegistry: '<?php serialize($objOne->myModelClass); ?>' }**

Answer (score 0):

В общих чертах:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "handler.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "myData=2",
    success: function(data){
       alert(data); // 20
    }
});
```

handler.php:

```
if($_POST['myData']) {

    $myData = $_POST['myData'];

    $instance = new Registry();

    echo $instance->someFunction($myData);

}

class Registry{

    public $field = "10";

    public function someFunction($args) {

        return $this->field * $args;

    }

}
```

**UPD:**
Подключение файла класса в обработчике: [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

handler.php:

```
spl_autoload_register('loadeClass');

fuction loadClass($class) {

    require_once 'путь/до/класса/' . $class . 'php';

}

$registry = new Regisrty();
```

Comment: Экземпляр класса был создан ранее и полям уже было присвоено значение. К нему мне и нужно получить доступ из файла handler.php.

Comment: Этот пример иллюстрирует общий принцип. Получили и проверили post, извлекли необходимые данные, передали соответствующему методу класса. Где и когда создавали экземпляр класса не важно.

Comment: @Артём Свистула я немного расширил пример в ответе

Comment: Так я ж и говорю, мне не нужно new Registry(). У меня уже есть экземпляр и к нему мне нужен доступ из  handler.php

Comment: Где и когда создавался экземпляр как раз важно. Если я обращусь к созданному ранее экземпляру класса из handler.php, мне выдаст ошибку.

Comment: в том комменте я полагал что вы класс описали в том же файле, handler.php . Теперь вы прояснили